# Openoffice headless on CentOS 7 / 8

Tags: centos, centos7, centos8, openoffice

We used to run Openoffice headless on CentOS 6.8 but are now upgrading to CentOS 8

However, I'm not able to install Openoffice headless using the following commands:

```
yum install openoffice.org-base
yum install openoffice.org-writer
yum install openoffice.org-headless
```

I keep getting the error (on both CentOS 7 and 8)

```
No match for argument: openoffice.org-base
Error: Unable to find a match: openoffice.org-base
```

As an alternative, I tried installing Openoffice from the tar file containing RPMs available on their official website. However, I'm not sure how to run it in headless mode.

Any help would be appreciated. My aim is to run openoffice headless on the command line so that we can do batch word to pdf conversions. This already works for me in CentOS 6.8 with Openoffice headless. But with CentOS 7 and 8, the above mentioned problems persist.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't LIbreOffice the current and more actively developed version of OpenOffice that you should be migrating to? At least that is the office suite that is included and supported by default. And doing the standard thing  is usually easiest to maintain as well, easier than keeping RPM's up2date that you manually downloaded...

"`yum group list hidden`" and `yum group info "Office Suite and Productivity"` possibly followed by `yum group install "Office Suite and Productivity"` should give you most of what you need.

Then further fine tuning in your scripts by using the libreoffice [`--headless`](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters) mode

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf my-report.docx
```